# MySQL: subtract different rows depending on different colums

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to substract numbers within different rows depending on different columns. I need to check if for a specific column, the value is always 0. Let me give you an example so that it will be easier to understand:

```
| user_id | circle | inv_number | status | account |
|---------|--------|------------|--------|---------|
| 100     | 001    | 0000010    | A      | 2000    |
| 100     | 001    | 0000010    | B      | -1500   |
| 100     | 001    | 0000010    | B      | -500    |
| 100     | 002    | 0000022    | A      | 3000    |
| 100     | 002    | 0000022    | B      | -500    |
| 100     | 002    | 0000022    | B      | -500    |
| 100     | 002    | 0000022    | B      | -500    |
| 100     | 002    | 0000022    | B      | -1000   |
```

As you can see inside the table I have a user with the `id=100`. I also have two different circles. For this example you do not need to understand what is meant with circle. Anyway I also have an `inv_number` and I have a `status`. The status always shows me `'A'` or `'B'`. If I now do `'A' - 'B'` I get for my `inv_number 0000010` the value `0`. If I do the same for my `inv_number 0000022` I would get `500` as my result.

Now I need to see all results, where the `account` field is not `0`. So in my example the result should look like this:

```
| user_id | circle | inv_number | status | account |
|---------|--------|------------|--------|---------|
| 100     | 002    | 0000022    | C      | 500     |
```

Can someone give me an example on how to achieve this? 
**Please note:** The subtraction depends on the columns `user_id`, `circle` and `inv_number`. I have multiple `user_ids` with multiple `circles` and multipe `inv_numbers`. So for every `inv_number` within the `circle` for a `user_id` the 'A' - 'B' substraction should work.

I tried with a subselect statement but it is not working because I knew I am missing a few informations like the `status` inside my sql statement:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    TABLENAME as t1

    LEFT JOIN TABLENAME2 as t2
        on t1.`user_id`=t2.`user_id`
        and t1.`circle`=t2.`circle`
        and t1.`inv_number`=t2.`inv_number`
WHERE
    `account` = (SELECT SUM((`inv_number`)-(`inv_number`)) AS total FROM TABLENAME2 GROUP BY t1.`user_id`,t1.`circle`, t1.`inv_number`);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Eh? What is 'c'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select user_id, circle, inv_number, 'C' as status,
       sum(account) as net
from t
where status in ('A', 'B')  -- not sure if this is necessary
group by user_id, circle, inv_number,
having sum(account) <> 0;
```

This sums the `account` column and keeps only combinations of `user_id`, `circle`, and `inv_number` where the sum is not `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Can you explain your code a little bit? What does <> 0 mean at the end for example?

Comment: I do get wrong results. Maybe it has something to do with your "-account"? Because inside the column account, the values already have an "-" before the number?

Comment: @ChristophC. . . . Yes, that is indeed the issue.  That allows the query to be simpler too.